# What is the best way for passing a deeply nested JSON object to a PureComponent prop in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a pure component that takes a prop which is basically a deeply nested JSON object like below:

```
const jsonObject = {
  prop1: {
    arrayProp: [],
  },
  prop2: 'string',
  prop3: {
    anotherprop: {
      someanotherprop1: {},
      someanotherprop2: {
        someArrayProp: [],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

---

**NOTE**: *In reality, this object is much more deeper, but for simplicity's sake, I provided a simpler object.*

---

And I pass this to my pure component in a parent component like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
      updateJSON = () => {
        const { jsonObject } = this.state;

        const updatedObject = _.cloneDeep(jsonObject);

        updatedObject.prop3.anotherprop.someanotherprop2.someArrayProp = [1, 2, 3];

        this.setState({ jsonObject: updatedObject });
      }


      render() {
        const { jsonObject } = this.state;
        return (
          <View>
            <MyPureComponent layout={jsonObject} />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.updateJSON} />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

If for example I change someArrayProp array using setState , will my purecomponent be updated or not?

For this specific case I can test it by myself but this is a generic question about how PureComponent conducts shallow comparison over such deep objects.

As far as i understand, a pure component has a built-in componentShouldUpdate hook that does a shallow comparison over props and decide whether the component should update or not.

This makes me think that due to my prop is deeply nested, it may sometimes miss to update the component since it may not detect a change in somewhere in my JSON tree.

Should i really worry about this and implement my on componentShouldUpdate function to check differences? 
Or should i create separate props based on my deeply nested JSON to overcome this issue?

Comment: Question is too broad, what is the scenario? How you pass props, how you update your `json` object? Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), using `componentShouldUpdate` / `PureComponent` highly depends on the situation

Comment: As `flatting` refers to `arrays`, making a `deep comparison` may lead to performance issues, as mentioned you need to elaborate much more.

Comment: Hi @DennisVash I updated my question with an example code. But yes you are right this is quite broad question since I need to build a generic approach about props handling when using pure components. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) and [`props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#props) need to be considered as **immutable**.

In your case, mutating the `someArrayProp` directly without making a new instance, will **not cause** a render.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { jsonObject } = this.state;

    // Some logic changing `jsonObject` like:
    jsonObject.prop3.anotherprop.someanotherprop2.someArrayProp = ['hello'];


    return <MyPureComponent layout={jsonObject} />;
  }
}
```

In the above case, while `MyPureComponent` is a `PureComponent`, the `shallow comparison` will compare the references which are the same.

```
class MyPureComponent extends PureComponent {

  /* PureComponent implements shallow comparison by default

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
     return this.props.layout !== next.props.layout;
  }

  */

  render() {}
}
```

That why [the best practice is not mutating data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { jsonObject } = this.state;

    // Some logic changing deep nested entry
    const someArrayChanged = ...;

    return <MyPureComponent layout={{ ...jsonObject, ...someArrayChanged }} />;
  }
}
```

> Should I really worry about this and implement my own `componentShouldUpdate` function to check differences? Or should I create separate props based on my deeply nested JSON to overcome this issue?

The answer depends on how you mutate the data, if directly - you should implement your own `componentShouldUpdate`, else, you don't need to worry.

In general, `componentShouldUpdate` is used when a component makes unnecessary renders due to failure of the default `shallow comparison`.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis but I am not directly mutating my object. I use setState instead as I said in my question. In that case, does your answer still stand?

Comment: **HOW** you calling the `setState`, it depends - as I said, you can still get the same result, you should show how you doing that

Comment: `setState` doing shallow merge, you still can mutate the state directly (common beginners mistake)

Comment: Ok. I added how i call setState.

Comment: Well, its deep clone so it **always** will re-render